# Execute Lua from string?

Tags: lua

I'm making a kind of Scratch variant for Lua, and I'm writing it in Lua, using Love. I want to be able to enter the code, and then execute the code from a string, and print out the results to a text box. I'm not sure how to do this.

I want the blocks to be put together, and then make a line of code each, and then execute the script as a whole.

Comment: A good starting point would be to look at the [`luaL_dostring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_dostring) function.

Comment: I think he wants a Lua function to do it, not a C function. `loadstring` seems to be what you want. (C-f loadstring in http://www.lua.org/pil/8.html)

Comment: Loadstring sounds like the way to go, he will have to set a variable to the value returned by loadstring and then call that though.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it will help You a little. I'm using VS2013,c++ and got such a code in my program:

```
static int printthis(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_dostring(L, "print(100)");
    return 0;
}
```

which prints "100" to my console :) when printthis is called